# How to clear ingress queue?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I sent 1000 invalid items for ingestion through LightIngest.exe. Each individual item takes around 10 minutes before it fails due to connectivity problems:

[image]

I am not able to proceed with valid items as they are added to the tail of the queue. How can I reset the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way today to reset or clear the queue. You have the following options:

1. Wait - the retries are exponential, so the impact of the rouge items will be diminished significantly as more time passes
2. Rename the table - the ingestions in the queue will fail and the queue will be cleared up. Please note however that when you rename the table back to the original name, items that are still waiting in the queue for a "retry" will continue to fail when their time arrives (since the table is back into its original name). So the closer that you do it to the actual error the better.

Comment: That is unfortunate :( I deleted the table, but the process is still very slow, though items fail with "Table 'T' in database 'D' could not be found" error.

Comment: The length of this process depends on how long it took you to rename/delete the table, if it was soon afterward, the queue would have been cleared fast since the difference between the retries is short, as time passes the time difference between the retires grows exponentailly and so does the time it takes the queue to clear.

Comment: I deleted it in 5-10 minutes maximum, as soon as it started to .show ingestion failures. Developers need to do something with that, it renders the cluster just unusable. In my case it was 2 days, but what if I put 10x or 100x of that? The queue must be visible and resettable.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Please do open an ask in http://aka.ms/kustouservoice

Comment: The ticket to vote: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/f447a1fc-eb24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0